Drools 8 - Decision table with "in" constraint take only first one item
I have a decision table which has a condition like myVariable in ($1) and rows like MyEnum.V1, MyEnum.V2, MyEnum.V3.
Drools generate only rule for the first value ignoring the others: myVariable in (MyEnum.V1).
How can I have Drools generating myVariable in (MyEnum.V1, MyEnum.V2, MyEnum.V3)?
Thanks!

What does this have to do with Java?

Well Drools is written in Java, can be embedded in Java applications and has a DSL that is somewhat similar to Java

I found the solution. One must use $param instead of $1.
$param take the whole cell content when $1 is intended to be used to reference first comma separated value in the cell, $2 the second value, etc.
